# Could MonoLocalBinds replace the MonomorphismRestriction

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, memoization

The main reason the `MonomorphismRestriction` exists is to avoid unexpected duplication of work.

One example is the following function:

```
len2 xs = (len, len)
    where len = genericLength xs
```

Which has the inferred type `(Num b, Num c) => [a] -> (b, c)` which can unfortunately lead to situations where things like `uncurry (+) . len2` actually computes `genericLength` twice despite it really only needing to compute it once.

However even without `MonomorphismRestriction`, the safer type `Num b => [a] -> (b, b)` is correctly inferred when you turn on `MonoLocalBinds`.

Given that `MonoLocalBinds` is automatically turned on with `GADTs`, with `TypeFamilies` and SHOULD be automatically turned on with `OVERLAPS` (but currently is not). It seems as though having `MonoLocalBinds` replace `MonomorphismRestriction` in the long run would make since. Particularly since it seems that there is a general consensus that `TypeFamilies` and `GADTs` are incredibly useful and might eventually be made standard.

Now certain things like:

```
foo = 8 ^ 8 ^ 8

bar = foo + foo
```

Still risk duplication. But I would argue that such expressions are not common enough in real code to warrant the pitfalls of `MonomorphismRestriction`.

Also if the `foo` is exported in the above example then I would argue it is correct to give it the type `Num a => a` even with the duplication risk, and if it is not exported then it seems like it should not be hard for the optimizer to remove the duplication within `bar`.

On a side note is there any chance Haskell will implement type specific memoization at some point in the future? Because that seems like it would very convenient for polymorphic top level computations.

Comment: Isn't [`SPECIALIZE`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#specialize-pragma) exactly the "type specific memoization" you are looking for?

Comment: @Alec looks like it is, I was kind of hoping for a more generic form that didn't require enumerating all the different types I wanted memoized. Also a way that would work pervasively for local and global bindings without significant code bloat.

Comment: It doesn't turn out to be _too_ bad. Also, if you want to delegate the writing of `SPECIALIZE` to call-sites (in a different module), you can just declare the  target function `INLINEABLE` and put the `SPECIALIZE` pragmas in another module... The docs go into some detail about this.

Comment: Is it possible to do `{-# SPECIALIZEALL #-}` or something like that where every type that GHC can guarantee is requested (not necessarily used, but just the types match up) is specialized?